# Catch the first mousewheel event when user scrolls and ignore the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to use the first mousewheel event when the user scrolls to perform an animation based on whether the user scrolls upward or downward. Currently I'm using `setTimeout` like this ( I'm using a plugin jquery.mousewheel.js )

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(animating)
    return;
    animating = true;
    /*animate according to sign of delta over here*/
    setTimeout(function() {animating=false;}, 1500);
})
```

This is working, but I also want that if the user scrolls again in-between before the timeout I want to identify that and and animate according to the new delta value. Is it possible programmatically or is there (any other) plugin that will allow me to do this.

Comment: y you are using jquery you can use jquery.one

Comment: i don't want the first one for the lifetime of the page, just once **everytime** the user scrolls and ignore the events that fire after that till the user scrolls again, how can i do that?

Comment: heres the plugin: [link](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

Comment: If it's working now, remove the timeout?